# html agility pack Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, html-agility-pack

I for parsing html use Html Agility Pack and so Grate stuff 
but i encountered some bad things :|
this is my Background Code

```
public static HtmlDocument GetXHtmlFromUri2(string uri)
    {
        HttpClient client = HttpClientFactory.Create(new CustomeHeaderHandler());


        var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument()
                                   {
                                       OptionCheckSyntax = true,
                                       OptionFixNestedTags = true,
                                       OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true,
                                       OptionReadEncoding = true,
                                       OptionDefaultStreamEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
                                   };

        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(client.GetStringAsync(uri).Result);

        return htmlDoc;

    }
```

i use html agility for WebApi (Mvc4) and this is Get Method Logic

```
//GET api/values
    public string GetHtmlFlights()
    {

        var result = ClientFlightTabale.GetXHtmlFromUri2("http://ikiafids.ir/departureFA.html");
        HtmlNode node = result.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[1]/tbody/tr[1]");

        string temp = node.FirstChild.InnerHtml.Trim();

        return temp;

    }
```

but when i Call this method (from Browser and Fiddler) encountered Exceptions , With this theme :

Object reference not set to an instance of an object, and this exception Is concerned this line

```
string temp = node.FirstChild.InnerHtml.Trim();
```

can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
var result = ClientFlightTabale.GetXHtmlFromUri2("http://ikiafids.ir/departureFA.html");
var tableNode = result.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[1]");

var titles = tableNode.Descendants("th")
                    .Select(th => th.InnerText)
                    .ToList();

var table = tableNode.Descendants("tr").Skip(1)
                    .Select(tr => tr.Descendants("td")
                                    .Select(td => td.InnerText)
                                    .ToList())
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: How can any of this td Attribution to Specific properties ?

Comment: `td.Attributes["someattribute"].Value`

Comment: sry but I want each of the elements (td) assignment to One Propertie like Model.FlightID

Answer (score 1):

I think your selector is wrong. Try this instead?

```
result.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table/tr[1]")
```